# issue using rails console building a Rails 5 api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I'm building an API with rails 5.
When I try to store a user with the Rails console I get the following error:

[image]

I cannot figure out what is the problem. 
I've run the migration

- set the model
- added the AMS gem
- added serializers
- added mime types

This is my schema

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `app/models/user.rb` file, it must be `ApplicationRecord`, not `applicationRecord`.